# Is it true that $|AQA|\leq A|Q|A$ if $A,Q$ are compact self-adjoint operators with $A\geq 0$?

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, analysis, spectral-theory, trace

Is it true that $|AQA|\leq A|Q|A$ if $A,Q$ are compact self-adjoint operators with $A\geq 0$ on a complex Hilbert space $H$? That is,
$$\langle x,|AQA|x\rangle\leq \langle x, A|Q|A x\rangle$$ for all $x\in H$, where $|Q|$ is the unique positive compact operator such that $|Q|^2=Q^*Q=Q^2$.

An attempt at starting. By the spectral theorem, $Q=UDU^*$ where $U$ is unitary and $D$ is diagonal consisting of the eigenvalues of $Q$. Then $|Q|=U|D|U^*$ where $|D|$ consists of the absolute values of the eigenvalues of $Q$.

Have no idea how to proceed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$A=\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix},\quad Q=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
Then $|Q|=I,$ hence
$$A|Q|A=\begin{pmatrix}
4 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$
On the other hand
$$AQA=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 2\\
2 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$ thus $$|AQA|=2I=\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0\\
0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}$$
Therefore the inequality $|AQA|\le A|Q|A$ fails.